# Image is not fitting in to height

Tags: android, imageview

I have an image, where the width is bigger than height. I want to fit the image in height with cropping the width. It should save ascpectRatio. The image should fit the image view.
I tried using `android:scaleType="centerCrop"`properties in XML but i did not get the same.

I tried 
`android:scaleType="fitXY"
       android:adjustViewBounds="true"`

Could you help me, please?
Below is the XML file.

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="riskmatix.be.bouwcampusvirtualtour.home.HomeActivity">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/background_image"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:src="@drawable/day"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

Comment: post your xml please

Comment: and post a screenshot if you can

Comment: @Vivek Sorry, I've added xml

Comment: see the answers .. and edit

Comment: Just to be sure: you want your image to keep ratio and fill the full height of the imageview resizing the width? can you post the screen of the image you are getting with adjustviewbounds?

Answer (score 0):

try this,
you need to set the width and height to match_parent

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:src="@drawable/ati"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"/>
```

Comment: Sorry, but I need not center part of image.

Comment: I need left one